# How to don't allow the user to enter an amount of more than 100

Tags: vb.net

I have this case where I need that the user enters some data. All I need is to allow the user to enter numbers from 0 to 100, if the user is entering an amount bigger than 100, than display a message like: `please enter number from 0 to 100` and then show them again where they need to enter that number.

For example, `Console.Write("Español:  ")` in the terminal is:

```
Español: ' the user should enter the number here
```

if the user enters more than 100, then display this:

```
Please enter number from 0 to 100. Español:  ' here enter the number again
```

I was thinking on doing this as in the code below, with an If ... Else, but, is there a better way?

Here is the actual code:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim Español1 As Integer
        Dim Matematicas1 As Integer
        Dim Ciencias1 As Integer
        Dim EstudiosSociales1 As Integer
        Dim Ingles1 As Integer
        Dim ArtesPlasticas1 As Integer
        Dim ArtesIndustriales1 As Integer

   Select Case Menu

    Case 2

        Console.Write("Ingrese las notas:    ")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Español:  ")
        ' I was thinking on doing this
        If Console.ReadLine() >= 100 Then
            Console.Write("La nota debe ser 100 o menos:  ")
            Español1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            Español1 = Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        If Español1 = True Then
            Console.Write("Matematicas:  ")
            Matematicas1 = Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        Console.Write("Ciencias:  ")
        Ciencias1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Estudios Sociales:  ")
        EstudiosSociales1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Ingles: ")
        Ingles1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Artes plasticas:  ")
        ArtesPlasticas1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Artes Industriales:  ")
        ArtesIndustriales1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Clear()

   End Select

End Sub
```

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldnt this be vb.net tagged?

Comment: This isn't VBA, it's only VB. Console.WriteLine etc. aren't possible in VBA.

Comment: @BennoGrimm I fix it already. Thanks!

Comment: Turn [Option Strict = On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). Fix the compiler errors first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really experienced with VB, but try this:

```
Dim n as Integer

n = Console.WriteLine()

Do While n >= 100
    Console.WiteLine("Enter new Value:")    'Sorry, no pienso la lengua español :(
    n = Console.ReadLine()
Loop
```

**Edit 3.0**
Add your subject names into the array `subjects`.

```
Sub Main()
Dim subjects As Array = {"Math", "English", "German"} 'Three example names
Dim subjectsInt As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim i, input As Integer
Dim check, FirstTry As Boolean

For i = 0 To (subjects.Length - 1)
    check = False
    FirstTry = True

    Do

        If FirstTry = True Then
            Console.WriteLine(subjects(i) & ": ")
            FirstTry = False
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 1 and 100" & " (" & subjects(i) & "):")
        End If

        input = Console.ReadLine()

        If input <= 100 And input > 0 Then
            subjectsInt.Add(subjects(i), input)
            check = True
        End If

    Loop While check = False

Next

For i = 0 To (subjects.Length - 1)
    Console.WriteLine(subjects(i) & ": " & subjectsInt(subjects(i)))
Next

Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I adapt it to my code? I am trying but I can't ;/

Comment: Instead of the `'I was thinking...` + 6 lines

Comment: I am getting an error: `Expression does not produce a value`

Comment: Although i see some other issues in your code... you declared `Espanol1` as Integer and later ask if it's `true`

Comment: I thought it was like in Javascript haha this is a pain in the ass. All I need is to don't allow the user to enter more than 100, how could it be hard?

Comment: Try this? Could work, if it doesn't tell me and axplain what your programm should do :)

Comment: It is just not working. With your solution I am still getting the same error: `Expression does not produce a value` and there is a new one: `Expression expected`. And what I told you before is: On `Console.Write("Español :")` the user should enter a value which should be less than `100`. In case it's more: display a message and show him again the `"Español: "` until the user enter the correct amount. And so on with the other `Console.Write()` and `Console.ReadLine()`. It should be the same for everything there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116925/discussion-between-benno-grimm-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Comment: With the last solution a new error came up: `Type 'Dictionary' is not defined.`

Comment: Hm, it works for me.. what program are you using?  I get a result like this http://imgur.com/Z6B3Y5t

Comment: Ok, just out of interest, what did you changed to make it work? :)

Comment: I did: `Dim subjectsInt As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer) `

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know VBA unfortunately . But I believe in every language is the same. You do a do {}while cycle and in the while you check if you conditions are met. And until they are met you continue reading from the console. Good look with your VBA :)